# include javascript files by xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

i have this code...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Client-Controls/ClientGridView.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var oScript = document.createElement("script");
        oScript.language = "javascript";
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.src = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        oHead.appendChild(oScript);
    }
</script>
```

this render some  but i cant use that javascript file functions... What can do the trick??

Comment: What do you mean by "*i cant use that javascrip file functions*"? What errors do you get?

Comment: Select the head element like this
 var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; Can you post what is in your xml file. And try without using oScript.type = "text/javascript";

Comment: i got no errors, that renders a <code><script type="text/javascript" src="some.jsp"></script><code> but i cant use the functions inside that javascript file

Comment: <scripts>
  <script>some.jsp</script>
  <script>anothersome.jsp</script>
</scripts>

Comment: You cannot include jsp file try to use js file it will definetly work. You want include a jsp file the  <%@include file="yourjsp.jsp" %> in your html page it cannot control by javascript

Comment: sorry is .js my mistake...

Comment: @user1977936 Your code is correct for include js file not jsp file

Comment: yes and it will render a <script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script> but in this file i have for example a function that alerts an hello, i call it after render and is not working

Comment: @user1977936 Give a some delay and then try to call the function. For me your code works perfectly and it shows alert. I try in firefox 18.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts will be loaded asynchronously so you can't use them right away.  Give them an onload handler so you know when they are ready:

```
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
oScript.type = "text/javascript";
oScript.src = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
oScript.onload = function () {
    // run bar, which is contained in foo.js
    bar();
};
oHead.appendChild(oScript);
```

---

If you want to make sure all your scripts have loaded, you can create a counter:

```
function counter(count, callback) {
    return function() {
        count -= 1;
        if (count === 0) {
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

and pass it to each load handler:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("script"),
    countdown = counter(x.length, function(){ alert("All scripts loaded!"; });
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text/javascript";
    oScript.src = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    oScript.onload = countdown;
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
}
```

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?  Are there error messages in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dennis's point, add a variable in the `Javascript` file that you're trying to get and check if that variable exists or if it's an interger, check the value. Anyway, you can easily do this in Javascript. Here's two ways.

**Option One**

```js
var neededScript = document.createElement("script");
n//if you want the script to be asynchronous, then set the async attribute like this:
neededScript.async="";
//then point the [src] attribute to the required script.
neededScript.src="src";
document.head.appendChild(neededScript);
```

Optionally, if you want to append the `script` to the `body`, then instead of `document.head.appendChild` use `document.body.appendChild`. You can append children to any element using either `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName` or if you want to filter elements by tag name (`<html>` is a tag) then use `document.getElementByTagName` or  - my personal favourite coming from jQuery - `document.querySelector`. You should read up on all of these methods as they are crucial to manipulating the DOM.
**Second Option**
Second option is using a very popular library called jQuery. It's syntax is a **lot** shorter than the document API syntax. It's main purpose is making DOM manipulation easier.

```js
var requiredScriptSrc="src";
$("head").append("<script src='"+requiredScriptSrc+"'></script>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery uses `selectors`, you should be familiar with them if you've tried CSS or `document.querySelector`.

**Option Three**
Option three is to use `custom tags` and a `for` loop that gets an attribute of the `custom tag` and creates a script element.

```js
for(var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("js-module").length; i++){
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("js-module")[i].getAttribute("src");
  var r = document.createElement("script");
  r.src = s;
  document.head.appendChild(r);
}
```

```html
<js-module src="src"></js-module>
```

If you need any more help, drop a comment on this post.